# VSCode Prettier plugin how to keep vertical spacing

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

So this is a weird one. I like most of the aspects of Prettier except it'll clear out vertical spacing that I purposely put in:

```
<main>

<div>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

and it will change it to this:

```
        <main>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Having extra vertical space between things helps me keep things organized and find things quicker. I looked through the settings of Prettier to see if anything was there but didn't see anything. Is there a way to have Prettier keep the vertical spacing I put in?

Comment: have you looked at all the settings for that formatter

Comment: I'm pretty new to VSCode extensions so I may have missed something but I only see an option to set the tab width, nothing for keep empty lines between code

Comment: what does the README of the prettier extension tell you which settings it has, it is not a one trick pony, everybody wants a different layout so it must have settings